# How do I make an pathfinding algorythm in lua / Roblox

Tags: algorithm, lua, roblox, path-finding, a-star

I know they already have one , but I want one that works in a grid.

- I would probably go with A*?
- I haven't seen any 3d examples.
- How would the nodes be set up , should I mark their neighbors or can the code just confirm them.

How would I go about making one?
If you don't know what lua is you could just explain a algorythm with words

I would like to make a grid pathfinding system different than the base pathfinding system which is more complicated and not in a grid.

I tried the forums, basic pathfinding tutorials (not in this language or platform), 2d example in studio by someone, but don't know how to turn it 3d (or yeah I could, but thats besides the point)

Comment: You could try searching “pathfinding algorithm with nodes roblox” into youtube

Comment: You want to make a grid pathfinding system that is not in a grid?

Comment: @OuterSoda , no I exactly want a grid pathfinding system